# How to add class to table element in ckeditor5 config?

Tags: html-table, ckeditor5

I am editing ckeditor5 config, and I need to add custom class to table. What I tried:

```
ckeditorConfigRegistry.add(config => ({
  toolbar: [...config.toolbar, 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor'],
  table: {
    customClass: ["table", "table-bordered"]
  }
}));
```

also tried:

```
table: {
    class: "table table-bordered"
  }
```

and:

```
table: {
    attributes: {
      class: "table table-bordered"
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to add class to table element in config?

Comment: As far as I see the common table plugin doesn't allow this but is rather working with inline style. Actually I consider this a bad solution, as long as not possible differently.